# Check if Div's content has been updated

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if a div's content is updated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#main').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
       alert("Div's content has been updated"); //Should display only once regarless the number of modified elements
   });
});
```

This code will alert **Div's content has been updated** the number of time the divs inside 
**#main** have been update

I would like it to alert only once, just to tell that, all the elements have been successfully updated. 
Any way to do this please? Thanks

Comment: @tel - because there is a specific jQuery function which is perfect for this situation :)

Comment: FWIW, mutation events are deprecated and were never broadly implemented. Use Mutation Observers instead: [spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutation-observers) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: You can set the hidden field on updating the content of div and can use the same to validate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [jQuery's `.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
document).ready(function(){
  $('#main').one('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
    alert("Div's content has been updated"); //Should display only once regarless the number of modified elements
  });
});
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LEMxB/)